# How to get "RestartCount" inside container

Tags: docker

I want to run a script for the 1st deploy of container, and no re-run if container restarted. I guest I can do it if I can get the "RestartCount" of the container's metadata inside it? Do you have any ideas about this one?

Comment: Should the initialization script run again if the container is deleted and recreated?

Comment: I want the initialization script will run at the 1st deploy - 1st time the container has started, not restarted or recreated

Comment: (Note that, in the extremely routine case of `docker stop; docker rm; docker run` a container to update it, the restart count of the new container will be 0.)